# Error "database schema could not be retrieved for this connection"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

[image]

Here's what my database looks like on my server under Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

[image: Management Studio]

I was hoping if I put my database code and my connection code, you guys could tell me what's wrong? I'm not sure what the problem is, I'm pretty sure the code is ok.

This is the database I created for movies -  `MovieDB`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[movie]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [genre] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [price] [float] NOT NULL,
    [rating] [float] NOT NULL,
    [director] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [image] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [review] [text] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[movie] ON
INSERT [dbo].[movie] ([id], [name], [genre], [price], [rating], [director], [image], [review]) VALUES (1, N'Guardians of the Galaxy', N'Action', 19.99, 7.6, N'James Gunn', N'../Images/Movies/GOTG-poster.jpeg', N'Gunn makes this huge entertainment accessible to the converted and the neophyte alike, and he has only has one goal: To send you out of the theater with a fat smile on your face. Mission accomplished.')
INSERT [dbo].[movie] ([id], [name], [genre], [price], [rating], [director], [image], [review]) VALUES (2, N'The Godfather', N'Drama', 9.99, 100, N'Francis Ford Coppola', N'../Images/Movies/Godfather.jpeg', N' The wedding sequence... is a virtuoso stretch of filmmaking: Coppola brings his large cast onstage so artfully that we are drawn at once into the Godfather world.')
INSERT [dbo].[movie] ([id], [name], [genre], [price], [rating], [director], [image], [review]) VALUES (3, N'Dawn of the Planet of the Apes', N'Action', 19.99, 7.9, N'Matt Reeves', N'../Images/Movies/Ape.jpeg', N' Director Matt Reeves, working from a script by Rick Jaffa, Amanda Silver and Mark Bomback, elevates the apes to primary importance in this intelligent thriller.')
INSERT [dbo].[movie] ([id], [name], [genre], [price], [rating], [director], [image], [review]) VALUES (4, N'Moonstruck', N'Romantic-Comedy', 6.13, 8.3, N'Norman Jewison', N'../Images/Movies/Moon.jpeg', N' In its warmth and in its enchantment, as well as in its laughs, this is the best comedy in a long time.')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[movie] OFF
```

And here is the connection code I have labeled `ConnectionClass.cs` under my `App_Code` folder in Visual Studio

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ConnectionClass
/// </summary>
public static class ConnectionClass
{
    private static SqlConnection conn;
    private static SqlCommand command;

    static ConnectionClass()
    {
        string connectionString = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["movieConnection"].ToString();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
    }

    public static ArrayList GetMovieByType(string movieType)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE type LIKE '{0}'", movieType);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string name = reader.GetString(1);
                string genre = reader.GetString(2);
                double price = reader.GetDouble(3);
                double rating = reader.GetDouble(4);
                string director = reader.GetString(5);
                string image = reader.GetString(6);
                string review = reader.GetString(7);

                Movie movie = new Movie(id, name, genre, price, rating, director, image, review);
                list.Add(movie);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

Finally, this is what I have in my `web.config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="movieConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MovieDB; Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot open database "MovieDB" requested by the login

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The message is pretty obvious. Your user cannot log in to the database.

Comment: How do you login into SSMS? Do you use your Windows account or you use a SQL Server account?

Comment: The error is specifically saying `Login failed for user ...`. Make sure SQL Server [allows for remote connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464.aspx) and user [is allowed to login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx#SSMSProcedure)(see the `Using SQL Server Management Studio` section.)

Comment: Have you granted the correct permissions to the user over the database? try connecting using the sa user or Windows credentials to see what happens,

Comment: @king.code I don't have any log in credentials, I'm just logging into my local server.

Comment: @poweredByOrange   I'm not trying to allow remote connections, I'm just trying to connect locally.  I'm not trying to make a public website.  I'm just learning this stuff.

Comment: @537mfb   Not sure if I have correct permissions.  I think I do.  I'll look into that

Comment: @user3577397 OK, but you totally ignored the second half of my comment. That is probably more important.

Comment: The poor man's way to test a connection..without code...is to setup a ODBC/DSN.  You cna delete it later.  Go to Control Panel , Admin Tools , ODBC (or DSN) .   Add a new system-dsn...just to see if you can get through.  Again, take your code out of the equation first...would be my advice.

Comment: I didn't ignore, I checked that as well.   I believe everything is ok with that.  The checkbox for users was selected in the login section

Comment: @granadaCoder  I think I did what you asked, and I couldn't get through.  I may have done something wrong tho, I am a noob with this stuff.

Comment: Phew! I got it.  Turns out my server name wasn't correct. I must have done some funky stuff during installation.  I needed to basically use the server it was trying to get into before, but then put my initials at the end of it.    Should I delete this thread?

Comment: That's why the poor's man's test works well.  It does the "basics" first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure you do the very basics first.

The poor man's way to test a connection..without code...is to setup a ODBC/DSN. You can delete it later. Go to Control Panel , Admin Tools , ODBC (or DSN) . Add a new system-dsn...just to see if you can get through. Again, take your code out of the equation first...would be my advice.

I would make sure you have the ServerName correct, and remember that sometimes SqlServer is installed under an "InstanceName".

So it would be either

1. SomeMachineName

or

2. SomeMachineName\SomeInstanceName

Once you "pass" that test.........then we can move on.